# Template choice not showing up with Wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type and activated page-attributes in the options. It works just fine (It allowed me to set parent and order), however the template drop down just doesn't appear? It works fine with regular pages.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't template drop down just for pages?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Post Types currently don't support the template features. Only 'pages' do.